# Good control for zooming and adding elements in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am writing application that will add usercontrol when user clicks on client area (but not on control that is in it), and will allow zoom on mousewheel occuring not only when mouse is over control. What would be good container control to use? I tried Canvas but it doesn't work as I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**3DTools** is a good tools for develop 3D features:

http://3dtools.codeplex.com

Easy zoom,camera,...

Answer (score 1):

look at these...

A WPF Custom Control for Zooming and Panning
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/zoomandpancontrol.aspx

Deep Zoom for WPF
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/DeepZoom.aspx